# Django: execute some code when devserver is started

Tags: django

I need to execute some code when devserver is started.

At the moment I just place the code into `models.py` inside one of my applications.

This solution has a side effect: the code is executed when other managements commands are used, and I'd like to avoid it.

**Updated:** This will be a part of distributable application. I don't want users (developers actually) to run any additional commands. They should be able to use the `runserver` command only. I also don't want to override `runserver` command with my own implementation.

**Updated:** My `models.py` looks like this:

```
from django.conf import settings

if settings.DEBUG: # I actually use another setting here, but it does not matter
    run_my_code_in_a_daemon_thread()
```

I don't have any actual models in this file. So, my code is executed only once: when Django scans all applications from INSTALLED_APPS and imports their `models.py`.

Answer (score 2):

Custom bash (python) launcher will be fine. Or you can write your own [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/).

Comment: I don't want to use another command or script. I need the code to run automatically when devserver is started.

Comment: @AndreyFedoseev Your code needs to be launched somehow, so you should write a launcher. Alternatively you can check if you are in dev mode (I do it with `platform.node()` but there are plenty of options).

Comment: I already have my code launched, see my question. I just need to ensure it's executed only by devserver only.

Comment: @AndreyFedoseev Your code is launched every time. That's why you need a special launcher. Three options: special launcher, checking for dev mode and dark magic. The last one isn't very reliable though. :-)

Comment: What do you mean by "every time"? It is launched only when `models.py` is imported. In my `models.py` I don't have any actual models, just a bit of code which I need to execute. So it's launched only once, when Django starts, scans all applications from INSTALLED_APPS and imports their `models.py`.

Comment: @AndreyFedoseev By every time I mean both with dev server and production server (or with any other server you have).

Comment: The code is disabled by default. It's launched only when a special option is enabled in settings.py.

Comment: @AndreyFedoseev Ok. The answer is still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply update your local `manage.py`? Check for the parameter that gets passed (you're interested in `runserver`, and if it does, execute the code you want from there. Something like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if sys.argv[1] == 'runserver':
        # Your custom code
    execute_manager(settings)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. I use zc.buildout and djangorecipe, it generates manage.py script for me. So all my changes will be lost when I rebuild Django instance.

Comment: In that case, DrTyrsa's answer applies: just create a (bootloader like) script that does the stuff you want to be done before the launch, and then let it run `python manage.py runserver`.